# Why does my basil have brown edges, yellowy spots, and split ends?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, plant-care, herbs, basil

There seem to be all sorts of problems with my basil but I can't figure the cause of it.

I've had it for a few weeks after buying it at the grocery store and it's been through a bit.

I transplanted it twice, splitting a part of it in a different pot the second time around and also left it outside a bit where it got wind blasted and chilled. (I didn't know that was bad and I regret it now.) I've placed it back inside by the window sill where it gets 4-6 hours of direct light everyday and water it every other day or so. I also ignorantly put a few drops of fertiliser after transplanting it which I also realized isn't good either.

I feel like a bad parent but does anyone know why my basil is still browning on the edges and drooping?

Also if anyone needs to know, I live in Vancouver BC. Thanks in advance!

[image]
[image]
(click to enlarge images)

Answer (score 4):

You might want to examine it closely with a magnifying glass to check for any infestation of insects or mites, but otherwise, the problems it has are probably cultural/environmental, partially from being mistreated in the ways you describe.

It's possible the brown edges are due to sitting behind a window with that many hours of sunlight - through glass, that will be pretty hot. As for the drooping, you may not have been watering enough. If its sat in sunlight for that many hours, I'd have expected it to need watering a little more often - I have to water mine daily at the moment because of higher air temperatures (although its in a smaller pot) and mine is on a windowsill that only gets about half an hour of sun at the end of the day.

Assuming the pot has drainage holes, water when the surface of the soil feels dry  to the touch, and water thoroughly, allowing the excess to flow away freely from the bottom of the pot. Empty out any outer tray under the pot 30 minutes after watering.